# ASP.NET MVC: converting virtualpath to actualpath is wrong

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I have been using Url.Content inside <%    and    %> in my views and all seems to be working fine... Then from withing my controller i have tried the following, but it always returns the wrong path

```
 XDocument xdoc = XDocument.Load(Url.Content("~/content/xml/faq.xml"));
```

and

```
 XDocument xdoc = XDocument.Load(VirtualPathUtility.ToAbsolute("~/content/xml/faq.xml"));
```

Basically the path shoudl be c:\Vs2008\Source\MyAppName.....

but its returning  c:\MyAppName.....

So its invalid,

Any ideas why this is happning?? Is there a work around?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's correct. I'm not sure why it's adding the C:\ but MyApp...\ is the absolute path.

Have you tried Server.MapPath?

Answer (score 5):

Those two methods are only meant to be used in the context of clients accessing content through your web server. To read a file internally, within the application you need to use Server.MapPath() or a similar method to get the physical path on your disk.

Answer (score 1):

I was having a similar problem linking to some .css and image files.  I wrote a blog post on this at http://www.stickfiguresoftware.com/node/46 that may be helpful and even has some sample code that I got to work.

Not sure it's the perfect solution, but it worked out for me.